# Locating the source of a persistent 120 Hz hum in amplifier

Tags: power-amplifier, hum

I'm working on rebuilding a subwoofer amplifier. The caps have been replaced, the corroded press-on tabs for transformer and speaker connections have been replaced.

Upon reassembly, the amplifier produces a low level 120 Hz-ish (what the iPhone RTA shows) that's consistent and not affected by any of the controls.

The amplifier also produces a loud thump or pop after a couple of seconds when it's unplugged from the wall.
Input is shorted for testing. I've clipped a gator clip from the RCA connectors to the steel plate the PCB mounts to to insure there's proper ground. No change in hum.

I've gone through and quadrupled checked everything, tested every diode and Zener in-circuit possible. I've run out of leads.

I'm suspecting the MUTE circuit as the cause, based on the thump on power down but not sure.

I've attached some photos of the schematic.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

[image: Paradigm1]

[image: Paradigm2]

Comment: What changes did you make? It only takes one bad connection to cause hum. If you modified the grouding and shielding, they may also make things worse.

Comment: I didn't modify the grounding at all. All I did was replace some corroded tabs for the speaker and transformer connections and all new caps.

Comment: Is the transformer tabs properly soldered and making good connection, especialy the "red" tab for ground? The schematics are very weird as if something is missing, what turns on the mains transformer if there is no power to turn it on? Have you measured all supplies to be OK? Which caps you replaced and with what caps, and what was the reason to change them? I'd be interested to know if you really changed **all** caps, as most likely most of the non-electrolytics were just fine and did not need replacing.

Comment: You're right, it was just the electrolytics. 
C25 - 100uf
C28 - 5600uf
C30 - 5600uf
C36 - 220uf
C38 - 22uf
C41 - 22uf
C42 - 22uf
C45 - 22uf

All are Panasonic FR and the filters are Nichicon

Comment: all tabs are making a good connector, have reflowed them

Answer (score 1):

Starting at the output and output power amplifier, it will be easy to use an oscilloscope or amplified speaker to probe signal test points in the circuit.